# how to use memalign with struct in c correctly?

Tags: c, memory, struct, barrier

I wrote the following code to allocate a chunk of memory for 10 of my struct barrier_t, but I keep getting the errors. What does it mean?and how to fix it? Thanks a lot!

> test2.c:19:16: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
>   test2.c:19:36: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
>   test2.c:19:40: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token

```
struct barrier_t {
    int count;
    bool local_sense;
};

struct barrier_t* barrier = NULL;

posix_memalign((void **) &barrier, 32, (sizeof(struct barrier_t)) * 10);
```

Comment: It seems you are making a function-call outside a function. (Hint: put the call to `posix_memalign` inside `main`)

Comment: You code in the question looks fine (suppose them in a function). Could you update your question to include the full `test2.c` in it?

Comment: you are right, Kninnug! I did not enclose the code in my main(). :D thanks a lot!